# Cannot access D-Link DES 3200-10 after resetting account

Tags: networking, router, switch, d-link

I've forgot my password and after googling I've found that in recovery mode I can reset my account.
Connected to Switch using console port (VT100+ Keyboard compatible) and pressed Shift+6. I accessed recovery mode successfully.
using the below command I reset (deleted all accounts as it show empty account by running show account)

```
#reset account
```

After rebooting I cannot access using empty username and password!
What am I doing wrong ?

```
                       DES-3200-10 Fast Ethernet Switch
                            Command Line Interface

                          Firmware: Build 4.38.B012
           Copyright(C) 2012 D-Link Corporation. All rights reserved.

Username:

User Access Verification

Username:

User Access Verification

Username:admin
Password:
Fail!
Password:
```

Comment: I am using PuTTY.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking your user manuals, I think that might be able to help you. There you can get your answers in Appendix A. Here is the link for your manual. if it works say it in comment. https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiI-s_lkaTNAhVLo48KHZlDC7gQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dlink.com%2Ffr%2Ffr%2F-%2Fmedia%2FBusiness_Products%2FDES%2FDES%25203200%2520Series%2FManual%2FDES_3200_Series_CLI_Ref_Guide_4_04.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEbSntiSrAGXDQqMtgvR9wSlsPrxw&bvm=bv.124272578,d.c2I&cad=rja